# Unstable data in kCBAdvDataManufacturerData

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

We get the BLE manufacturer data being advertised by using the `centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI`
method.

Apparently, the data arrived in the specific field of `kCBAdvDataManufacturerData` is unstable and many times is just 0. To compare with Android, this information is received via the ScanRecord byte array and is received correctly all the time.

Comment: Do you find solution for this @Simon ? My problem is same with you .  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402904/is-there-any-way-access-manufacturer-data-from-ios-device

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
manufacturerData = [advertisementData objectForKey:@"kCBAdvDataManufacturerData"];
const char *valueString = [[manufacturerData description] cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```