# Is there any way access manufacturer data from iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

Maybe this question duplicate but my situation is different from others. 
I have a own bluetooth kit. It puts manufacturer spesific data when click button on kit. I'm getting manufacturer data from android. But I cannot access from ios app.

I listen advertising data as below :

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

        for (key,value) in advertisementData{
            print("key:\(key) value:\(value)")     
           }

 }
```

And log result :

```
key:kCBAdvDataIsConnectable value:1
key:kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs value:(1802)
key:kCBAdvDataLocalName value: R009
```

By the way, I tried CoreLocation api for seeing my ble devices.

```
func startScanBeacons() {
    let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "b9407f30-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d")!
    let beaconRegion =   CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid, identifier: "mybeacon")
    beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = true
    beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = true
    locationManager.startMonitoring(for:beaconRegion)
    locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion)
}
```

But it didn't work. My device doesn't show as beacon. After some research on stackoverlow, some people say : this is not possible. 
You can look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46373130/3170065. 
But there must be a workaround getting manufacturer data. What should I do to overcome this problem ?  We can customize ble firmware.

Comment: It may need some permission ? Thought i have not worked on it but i think privacy permission could do the trick.

Comment: Or you may try for permission using keys like we access contact info by giving it keys that we require.

Comment: I granted all related permission. @AbuUlHassan

Comment: ahan okay i will check if found i'll get back to you :)

Comment: The related question is about setting custom Manufacturer Data when the device acts as a Peripheral. But in your case your iDevice acts as a Central, it's your other device which is a Peripheral, right? Does `didDiscover:` gets called more than once for the same device? If not, you may want to change the scanning options. What I guess is the issue is that adv data cames into chunk, and maybe in the first, it doesn't include the manufacturer data.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your anwser. Same devices called more than once in didDiscover. Every time  called didDiscover when I press the button on kit. But manufacturer data always  nil. @Larme